How can I use prometheus to accurately track counter metrics for a time range?
Setup
I have jobs that run that handle syncs between two data sources. They emit otel counter metrics of the number of records that have been ingested.
These get pushed to the otel collector, which then end up in Prometheus.
Each run has a few tags associated with it: accountId, jobId, runId.
These metrics reset after a few minutes because they will never appear again due the the runId never resurfacing. So on the prometheus graph they appear for about 5 minutes, then go away.
Problem
I'm trying to query Prometheus given these metrics to get an accurate count of records ingested for a given time range. I'm trying to use this for billing so that I can get a count of records for a given month.
Simply put, I want to query prometheus for a month, say April, or May, and get a count starting 0 of the number of records seen that month.
I have this script here that seems to work: https://gist.github.com/nickzelei/43486b05a7c58133a7aecd23f67de54d
But I'm worried about the longterm or if I'm doing something really inefficient.
It doesn't seem like it should be this difficult, and maybe I'm using the wrong tool here, any recs would be great.

I ended up solving this in a simpler way that is much lighter on the server.
Full script is here: https://gist.github.com/nickzelei/74bc7016be4cbc6041ce80585dfe2df9
In short, the query I'm using is:
sum(max_over_time(<metric>[1d]))

I do this using the Query method instead of QueryRange. I wrote a script that makes this query for each day, which calculates the daily total.
For monthly total, I set the day end for the end of the month and update the time window to be [30d].
